# Degrees of extensions by $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_p$ of $\mathbb Q$ and $ L$ where $ \mathbb Q \leq L$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose that we have a finite extension $\mathbb Q \leq L$ and that the prime $p\nmid |L:\mathbb Q|$. Suppose also that $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_p \notin \mathbb Q$

Is it true that $|L(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_p):L| \leq |\mathbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_p): \mathbb Q| $?

If not could someone please provide me with a counter example? I've checked a few examples and I think this has held up so far.

Comment: Why do you expect the number of elements you adjoint to be related to the degree of the original extension in this way?

Answer (score 1):

> If $F\leq K$ and $F\leq L$, $$\color{red}{[L:F] \geq [LK:K]} \iff [LK:L] \leq [K:F]$$
>   To see why, just note the diagram below, where arrows represent inclusion.
>   $\require{AMScd}$\begin{CD}K @>>> LK \\
> @AAA @AAA \\
> F @>>> L
> \end{CD}

The inequality in red is true because, by second isomorphism theorem:
$$[LK:K] = [L:L\cap K] \leq [L:F]$$

Taking $F=\mathbb{Q}, K=\mathbb{Q}(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ immediately answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for this! This makes sense to me mostly, apart from the relation that $L(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_p) = L\mathbb Q(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_p)$. Is this true because everything in $L(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_p)$ is some "polynomial" in that $\alpha_i$'s with coefficients in $L$ and elements of $L$ are $\mathbb Q$-linear combination of some set of elements of $L$?

Comment: @user366818  Yes exactly.